# top matching cells only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple formula in an excel sheet with 3000 rows, is there is a way to to return only a certain percentage of the top matching cells only. I only want the top  9% (270 rows) that match my criteria to be shown and other rows to be hidden

Here is my formula:

```
= IF(AND(H2=1,O2>=58)," A",IF(AND(H2=2,O2>=58)," B",IF(AND(H2=5,O2>=55)," C")))
```

I did it with pivot table but want to do it in the same sheet within the same formula adding to it to get what I need.
Thanks

Comment: Something like: `=INDEX(SORT(A1:A3000,,-1),SEQUENCE(270))`, but not sure about what exactly you are after.

Comment: Ibra - couldn't you just use a filtering option such as "top x%"?

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9-UHKMaexC-OjLm0F?e=8DXK60) refer:

[image: Screenshot - double filter]

```
=LET(fil,FILTER($C$4:$C$3000,--($C$4:$C$3000>=500)),FILTER(fil,--(fil>=PERCENTILE(fil,E3))))
```

**Pre-requisite:** Office 360 compatible version of Excel

**Notes:** cell E3 (screenshot) = 8% (custom format type, including apostrophes: `"top "0%" of filtered"`; likewise, cell I3 type: `"top "0%`)

**Advantages:**

1. Auditability
2. Understandability
3. Preserves original ordering
4. Moderate calc. speed
5. Quick implementation
6. No interim calcs

**Disadvantages:**

1. Requires Office 360

**References:**

- Let function [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) - not essential but quite useful/convenient (alternative, longer version to above becomes cumbersome/unwieldy to work with - likely to be relatively more error-prone than more succinct/parsimonious equivalent hence provided)
- Filter [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)